# Building OpenImageIO on Kubuntu 14.10: make error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boost, build, makefile

bit of a newbie to Ubuntu here and this has really been confusing me.

Currently trying to build OpenImageIO using make, following the steps outlined here: https://sites.google.com/site/openimageio/checking-out-and-building-openimageio

As far as I'm aware, I have installed all of the dependencies, however trying to run make gives me the following error:

```
platform=linux64, hw=x86_64
OPENIMAGEIO_SITE = shanesimmsart-pc
dist_dir = dist/linux64
INSTALLDIR = /home/shanesimmsart/oiio
( cd build/linux64 ; make  )
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/build/linux64'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/build/linux64'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/build/linux64'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/build/linux64'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/build/linux64'
[  0%] Building CXX object src/libutil/CMakeFiles/OpenImageIO_Util.dir/strutil.cpp.o
/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/src/libutil/strutil.cpp: In function ‘OpenImageIO::v1_6::string_view OpenImageIO::v1_6::Strutil::parse_nested(OpenImageIO::v1_6::string_view&, bool)’:
/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/src/libutil/strutil.cpp:768:28: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
     for ( ; nesting && len < p.size(); ++len) {
                            ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [src/libutil/CMakeFiles/OpenImageIO_Util.dir/strutil.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/build/linux64'
make[2]: *** [src/libutil/CMakeFiles/OpenImageIO_Util.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/build/linux64'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shanesimmsart/oiio/build/linux64'
make: *** [cmake] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong / might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you're using has enabled the `-Werror` flag by default, which forces the compiler to treat all warnings as errors.  This is always a bad idea for shipping code to users, because users will have a wide variety of different compilers and versions of compilers, so users will get different warnings than developers.  When developers build the code they should absolutely use `-Werror`.  When developers ship code to users, they should absolutely *not* enable `-Werror` by default.

Anyway, looking at the code in Git it appears that if you do this:

```
make STOP_ON_WARNING=no
```

it will disable `-Werror`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, did this and solved my problems, although instead I set flags in CMakeLists.txt:

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wno-sign-compare -Wno-conversion-null" )